# Why does hg purge abort complaining about *.* - only the first time?

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to track down why Mercurial is crashing during a `purge` operation on a Win7 machine. It fails with this message:

```
abort: The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\working\app/Build/deploy/x86/*.*'
```

after which the hg process terminates.

The path `C:\working\app/Build/deploy/x86/` is a valid, existing folder (despite the strange variation in slashes).

HG is run as follows from `c:\working` as the current directory:

```
hg purge --config extensions.purge= --all --dirs --files
```

At first I thought that there could actually be a file named "`*.*`" but that is not the case.

*If I run it a second time, immediately afterwards, it works.* (This is unsatisfactory, however, because the first failure causes an automated build script to fail.)

I also tried to look for NTFS hard links which could be malformed, maybe having `*.*` actually in the link definition, but that doesn't seem to be the problem either (I used https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html to exhaustively enumerate all links in the folder tree).

Using Mercurial 4.6.1.